# Vue3 won't trigger watch when using v-model:prop="data"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm creating a child component for my filters which should be updated when the user changes some input values... The problem is that when I emit the new data into the parent component the watch won't trigger! Please review my code to see where I went wrong...

#### Parent Component

###### Defining the component

```html
<FiltersComponent v-model:filters="filters" />
```

###### Defining the watch expression

```js
watch(filters, (value) => {
  getAccounts(value);
});
```

#### Child Component

```js
const emits = defineEmits(['update:filters']);
const props = defineProps({
  filters: {
    type: Object,
    default: () => ({
      ...
    }),
    required: true,
  },
});

function updateFilters(newValue, property) {
  console.log('updateFilters', newValue, property);
  emits('update:filters', { ...props.filters, [property]: newValue });
}
```

note: the console.log prints the newValue and property correctly but the watch never happens!

PS: I used the `v-on:update:filters="getAccounts(filters)"` inside parent component too. but the filters data is not updated inside function call...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to set deep to true when watching an array or object so that Vue knows that it should watch the nested data for changes. Try using this:

```
    watch(filters, (value) => {
      getAccounts(value);
    },
      {
       deep: true
      }
    );
```

For reference please review the vue 3 documentation:
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/watch.html#_3-x-syntax